# How do i get data from object and create array of objects?

Tags: javascript, json

As you can see i have multiple objects now after converting this to array and having all of these inside array what i want to do is get a new array that should have captain name and all the scores with round number in a object and all of these objects should be saved like that in array.
A representation of what i want to be achieved would be something like this
 `[{captain:'John Doe',RoundNumber:Score},{captain:'John Doe',RoundNumber:Score},{captain:'JohnDoe',RoundNumber:Score}]`

this is the result im trying to achieve some help or guidance would be much appreciated below is the data

````
    "-MXePKlz_DH8qqrIyesI" : {
      "game_name" : "test101",
      "players_info" : {
        "captain" : "john",
        "stage_name" : "fun fin fo",
        "team_members" : "John,Jane,jaden"
      },
      "response" : "this is one response",
      "round_num" : "1",
      "score" : "1"
    },
    "-MXePV53h9yol1UcLd8v" : {
      "game_name" : "test101",
      "players_info" : {
        "captain" : "Hamza",
        "stage_name" : "dssd",
        "team_members" : "01,02,03,05"
      },
      "response" : "another test response....!!!",
      "round_num" : "1",
      "score" : "0"
    },
    "-MXeiS_NOtxh3zSsG5sy" : {
      "game_name" : "mtest",
      "players_info" : {
        "captain" : "B",
        "stage_name" : "baj",
        "team_members" : "S"
      },
      "response" : "He is just gorgeous ",
      "round_num" : "1",
      "score" : "6"
    },
    "-MXeiTyNgMrIPKy2V_GG" : {
      "game_name" : "mtest",
      "players_info" : {
        "captain" : "Mo",
        "stage_name" : "fun fin fo",
        "team_members" : "Its Just Me and myself :)"
      },
      "response" : "Thats the same joke we had last week",
      "round_num" : "1",
      "score" : "4"
    },
    "-MXeiUGSqOvJdhHh64Vl" : {
      "game_name" : "mtest",
      "players_info" : {
        "captain" : "Schmed",
        "captain_email" : "SchmedtheEd@gmail.com",
        "stage_name" : "Schmed",
        "team_members" : "Schmed, Ed, Ted, Fred"
      },
      "response" : "Beard",
      "round_num" : "1",
      "score" : "2"
    }
  }```
````

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: its messed up i've tried to achieve this by using nested loops that didnt work out i can push this into new array but again there are many objects with same captain name different index and different round number so even if im to push this into new array so when same captain name comes on different index how do i add round number and score to that previous object. Ive tried multiple solution so i dont have one solid right now so this is the concept all i have in mind right now.

Comment: @MuhammadHamza did the answer below work for you ?

Comment: no sir it didn't let me explain once so that you can understand it better lets say i have these objects that i posted above so each object will have different index but not all are going to have different captain so what i want to do is that create a new array that should have objects now in each object it should contain captain name and scores collected from all the other objects that have same captain name and then same stuff to next one untill i have an array that contain each object with a captain name and all the scores from round that one captain had so i could display by cap name.

Comment: @MuhammadHamza I updated my answer, hopefully that's what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say keep your data as an object and do this:
Here I have player: john listed twice with 2 scores, first 1 and second 3. the result should list John once with score of 4 total.

```js
var myData = {
    "-MXePKlz_DH8qqrIyesI": {
      "game_name": "test101",
      "players_info" : {
        "captain" : "john",
        "stage_name" : "fun fin fo",
        "team_members" : "John,Jane,jaden"
      },
      "response" : "this is one response",
      "round_num" : "1",
      "score" : "1"
    },
  "-MXePKlz_DH8qqrIyes55": {
      "game_name": "test101",
      "players_info" : {
        "captain" : "john",
        "stage_name" : "fun fin fo",
        "team_members" : "John,Jane,jaden"
      },
      "response" : "this is one response",
      "round_num" : "1",
      "score" : "3"
    },
    "-MXePV53h9yol1UcLd8v" : {
      "game_name" : "test101",
      "players_info" : {
        "captain" : "Hamza",
        "stage_name" : "dssd",
        "team_members" : "01,02,03,05"
      },
      "response" : "another test response....!!!",
      "round_num" : "1",
      "score" : "0"
    },
    "-MXeiS_NOtxh3zSsG5sy" : {
      "game_name" : "mtest",
      "players_info" : {
        "captain" : "B",
        "stage_name" : "baj",
        "team_members" : "S"
      },
      "response" : "He is just gorgeous ",
      "round_num" : "1",
      "score" : "6"
    },
    "-MXeiTyNgMrIPKy2V_GG" : {
      "game_name" : "mtest",
      "players_info" : {
        "captain" : "Mo",
        "stage_name" : "fun fin fo",
        "team_members" : "Its Just Me and myself :)"
      },
      "response" : "Thats the same joke we had last week",
      "round_num" : "1",
      "score" : "4"
    },
    "-MXeiUGSqOvJdhHh64Vl" : {
      "game_name" : "mtest",
      "players_info" : {
        "captain" : "Schmed",
        "captain_email" : "SchmedtheEd@gmail.com",
        "stage_name" : "Schmed",
        "team_members" : "Schmed, Ed, Ted, Fred"
      },
      "response" : "Beard",
      "round_num" : "1",
      "score" : "2"
    }
}

var myNewArray = [];
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(myData)) {

  let player = myNewArray.find( e => e.captain === value.players_info.captain );
    
  if (player) {
    player.RoundNumber = Number(player.RoundNumber) + Number(value.score);
  } else {
    myNewArray.push({
      captain: value.players_info.captain,
      RoundNumber: value.score
    });
  }
}

console.log(myNewArray);
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Comment: @MuhammadHamza can you please mark it as the correct answer so other people can use it too ?